# Full GC due to concurrent mode failure

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am using Java 6_13.

My gc.log shows that I run into concurrent mode failure. However, part of the line shown here confuses me a lot since the Full GC does not clean the memory but instead increases the occupied memory.

```
(concurrent mode failure): 778598K->781522K(786432K), 1.2618790 secs]
```

Is it normal? In addition, if anyone has any explanations on why I run into this problem, please share too. As this problem does not always happen when I do load testing, but when it happens, it slows everything down (which is quite expected as a result of Full GC).

I also include my log here in case you need a complete picture.

```
2014-12-17T10:36:21.839-0500: 22.094: [GC 22.094: [ParNew: 262144K->5947K(327680K), 0.0186840 secs] 262144K->5947K(720896K), 0.0188600 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.02, real=0.02 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:37:40.865-0500: 101.119: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(393216K)] 133041K(720896K), 0.1643040 secs] [Times: user=0.16 sys=0.01, real=0.17 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:37:41.029-0500: 101.284: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-12-17T10:37:41.210-0500: 101.464: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.067/0.180 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.01, real=0.18 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:37:41.210-0500: 101.464: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:37:41.256-0500: 101.510: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.044/0.046 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:37:41.256-0500: 101.510: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:37:45.249-0500: 105.503: [GC 105.503: [ParNew: 268091K->55535K(327680K), 0.0379060 secs] 268091K->55535K(720896K), 0.0381190 secs] [Times: user=0.18 sys=0.05, real=0.03 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2014-12-17T10:40:13.781-0500: 254.036: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.246/152.525 secs] [Times: user=14.81 sys=1.02, real=152.51 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:40:13.782-0500: 254.036: [GC[YG occupancy: 181472 K (327680 K)]254.036: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0427610 secs]254.079: [weak refs processing, 0.0017680 secs]254.081: [class unloading, 0.0083440 secs]254.090: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0096400 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 0K(393216K)] 181472K(720896K), 0.0638280 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.01, real=0.06 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:40:13.846-0500: 254.101: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2014-12-17T10:40:13.879-0500: 254.134: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.033/0.033 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:40:13.880-0500: 254.134: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2014-12-17T10:40:13.885-0500: 254.139: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.005/0.005 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:17.055-0500: 497.309: [GC 497.310: [ParNew: 317679K->65536K(327680K), 0.1915580 secs] 317679K->117282K(720896K), 0.1917720 secs] [Times: user=0.62 sys=0.08, real=0.19 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:18.806-0500: 499.061: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 51746K(393216K)] 243278K(720896K), 0.0321840 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:18.839-0500: 499.093: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-12-17T10:44:19.919-0500: 500.174: [GC 500.174: [ParNew: 327680K->64521K(327680K), 0.0353730 secs] 379426K->149606K(720896K), 0.0356140 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:21.201-0500: 501.455: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.105/2.362 secs] [Times: user=3.07 sys=0.85, real=2.36 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:21.201-0500: 501.455: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:44:21.242-0500: 501.497: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.038/0.041 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:44:21.242-0500: 501.497: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:30.890-0500: 631.144: [GC 631.145: [ParNew: 326364K->26707K(327680K), 0.0217020 secs] 411449K->111798K(720896K), 0.0219820 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2014-12-17T10:46:31.979-0500: 632.233: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.040/130.736 secs] [Times: user=12.26 sys=1.46, real=130.72 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:32.009-0500: 632.264: [GC[YG occupancy: 161330 K (327680 K)]632.264: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0620470 secs]632.326: [weak refs processing, 0.0017350 secs]632.328: [class unloading, 0.0114700 secs]632.339: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0088820 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 85090K(393216K)] 246420K(720896K), 0.0858470 secs] [Times: user=0.43 sys=0.01, real=0.08 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:32.096-0500: 632.350: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:32.591-0500: 632.846: [GC 632.846: [ParNew: 288851K->65536K(327680K), 0.1166790 secs] 373892K->298985K(720896K), 0.1170040 secs] [Times: user=0.52 sys=0.06, real=0.12 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:33.741-0500: 633.995: [GC 633.995: [ParNew: 322304K->65536K(327680K), 0.1065110 secs] 555561K->477757K(744488K), 0.1067870 secs] [Times: user=0.48 sys=0.09, real=0.10 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:33.950-0500: 634.204: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.109/1.854 secs] [Times: user=12.42 sys=0.42, real=1.86 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:33.951-0500: 634.205: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:34.038-0500: 634.292: [GC 634.292: [ParNew: 327374K->64235K(327680K), 0.3638820 secs] 739596K->738053K(1014720K), 0.3641410 secs] [Times: user=0.72 sys=1.30, real=0.37 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:34.462-0500: 634.716: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.006/0.511 secs] [Times: user=1.71 sys=1.32, real=0.51 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:34.521-0500: 634.776: [GC 634.776: [ParNew: 324988K->324988K(327680K), 0.0000430 secs]634.776: [CMS: 673817K->686118K(687040K), 1.2695600 secs] 998806K->941293K(1014720K), [CMS Perm : 58268K->57873K(86016K)], 1.2711070 secs] [Times: user=1.26 sys=0.01, real=1.27 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:35.797-0500: 636.052: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 686118K(786432K)] 957705K(1441792K), 0.0145640 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:35.812-0500: 636.067: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:42.519-0500: 642.774: [Full GC 642.774: [CMS2014-12-17T10:46:42.763-0500: 643.018: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.271/6.951 secs] [Times: user=31.85 sys=5.96, real=6.95 secs] 
 (concurrent mode failure): 711857K->775949K(786432K), 1.7010100 secs] 1367217K->1071092K(1441792K), [CMS Perm : 58431K->58320K(86016K)], 1.7013000 secs] [Times: user=1.96 sys=0.01, real=1.71 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:47.668-0500: 647.922: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 775949K(786432K)] 1181108K(1441792K), 0.1282060 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.13 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:47.797-0500: 648.051: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:47.979-0500: 648.234: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.167/0.183 secs] [Times: user=0.53 sys=0.02, real=0.18 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:47.979-0500: 648.234: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:48.209-0500: 648.463: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.229/0.229 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:48.209-0500: 648.463: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2014-12-17T10:46:48.209-0500: 648.463: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.000/0.000 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:48.209-0500: 648.464: [GC[YG occupancy: 411214 K (655360 K)]648.464: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.1109340 secs]648.575: [weak refs processing, 0.0028000 secs]648.578: [class unloading, 0.0214210 secs]648.599: [scrub symbol & string tables, 0.0097890 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 775949K(786432K)] 1187163K(1441792K), 0.1492660 secs] [Times: user=0.81 sys=0.00, real=0.15 secs] 
2014-12-17T10:46:48.359-0500: 648.614: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2014-12-17T10:47:06.474-0500: 666.729: [Full GC 666.729: [CMS2014-12-17T10:47:06.493-0500: 666.747: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.105/18.133 secs] [Times: user=11.42 sys=0.74, real=18.13 secs] 
 (concurrent mode failure): 778598K->781522K(786432K), 1.2618790 secs] 1433958K->1056111K(1441792K), [CMS Perm : 58638K->58559K(86016K)], 1.2621660 secs] [Times: user=1.26 sys=0.00, real=1.26 secs]
```

Comment: I recommend looking at other CMS and concurrent mode failure related answers, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918124/how-to-reduce-java-concurrent-mode-failure-and-excessive-gc

Comment: I took a look at the link you gave, but still not be able to understand why the Full GC operation does not clean the memory but causes an increase in the occupied memory.